# Proof between different maps possibly using injectivity and surjectivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have the following here:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y,g:Y \rightarrow X$, and $h: Y \rightarrow X$ are functions such that $g \circ f=1_X$ (The $1_X$ being identity) and $f \circ h = 1_Y$. Show that $g=h$.

I'm given a hint that $g=g \circ1_Y$.

How would I go about doing this?

I see definitions of Surjectivity, bijectivity etc... I can use but I am not sure if that's the right approach.

I know that $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective which is fine but how can I proceed from this? I am not really sure how to structure this proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that by substitution and associativity, we have $$g = g ∘ 1_Y = g ∘ (f ∘ h) = (g ∘ f) ∘ h = 1_X ∘ h = h$$

Comment: I really overthought that. Thanks a lot!